# Como mantener el <section> y el <aside> del mismo tamaño?

Tags: html, css

Estoy aprendiendo HTML y CSS por mi cuenta, pero me queda una duda como hago para que el section y el aside se mantengan del mismo tamaño conforme vaya agregando mas articles dentro del section vaya que los tamaños (y colores de fondo) se mantengan igual.

```
    <section class="content">
        <article class="article" >
            <h2>Titulo del articulo</h2>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque aliquid esse perferendis voluptates eius iure reprehenderit mollitia quis quos repudiandae, asperiores adipisci in unde labore laudantium corrupti provident, cupiditate molestias?</p>
        </article>
        <article class="article" >
            <h2>Titulo del articulo</h2>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque aliquid esse perferendis voluptates eius iure reprehenderit mollitia quis quos repudiandae, asperiores adipisci in unde labore laudantium corrupti provident, cupiditate molestias?</p>
        </article>
        <article class="article" >
            <h2>Titulo del articulo</h2>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque aliquid esse perferendis voluptates eius iure reprehenderit mollitia quis quos repudiandae, asperiores adipisci in unde labore laudantium corrupti provident, cupiditate molestias?</p>
        </article>
        <article class="article" >
            <h2>Titulo del articulo</h2>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque aliquid esse perferendis voluptates eius iure reprehenderit mollitia quis quos repudiandae, asperiores adipisci in unde labore laudantium corrupti provident, cupiditate molestias?</p>
        </article>
        
    </section>

    <aside>
        <h2>Barra lateral</h2>
        <form>
            <input type="text">
            <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
        </form>
        <h3>Titulo aside</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Maiores nam quibusdam modi, assumenda reiciendis perspiciatis. Soluta ut fuga maiores ipsam inventore, dolorum quis rerum rem sunt animi. Dolorem, fugit consectetur!</p>
    </aside>
```

[image: CSS]

[image: PAGINA]

Comment: Al elemento aside le tienes un width 20% - 20px por eso te queda ese espacio vacio. Y el height si le pones 100% te ocupa el 100% de la altura del elemento que la contiene

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código como tal en lugar de usar screenshots, por favor.

Comment: Gracias. @DjCrazy Cuando agrego el código no me deja guardar la pregunta me sale que es puro código, por eso agregue una screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenté crear un diseño responsive, espero te sirva. Lo recomendable en los sitios es que `aside` ocupe todo el alto y se quede fijo, ya dentro de el puede meter ya sea un contenido que pueda o no abarcar el alto o incluso hacerle scroll.

Espero te sirva

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: auto !important;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 0 3.5em;
}

aside {
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 3.5em;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.article {
  color: #FFF;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px lightcoral;
}

footer {
  height: 40px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section class="content">
  <article class="article">
    <h2>Titulo del articulo</h2>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque aliquid esse perferendis voluptates eius iure reprehenderit mollitia quis quos repudiandae, asperiores adipisci in unde labore laudantium corrupti provident, cupiditate molestias?</p>
  </article>
  <article class="article">
    <h2>Titulo del articulo</h2>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque aliquid esse perferendis voluptates eius iure reprehenderit mollitia quis quos repudiandae, asperiores adipisci in unde labore laudantium corrupti provident, cupiditate molestias?</p>
  </article>
</section>
<aside>
  <h2>Barra lateral</h2>
  <form>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
  </form>
  <h3>Titulo aside</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Maiores nam quibusdam modi, assumenda reiciendis perspiciatis. Soluta ut fuga maiores ipsam inventore, dolorum quis rerum rem sunt animi. Dolorem, fugit consectetur!</p>
</aside>
```